# Issue using methods and an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

My problem here is displaying the data using another method. I tried both of the         methods but there was no output.

I think that objects in the ArrayList are gone when I made them as parameters on both methods or maybe not.

Please kindly help me with this problem of mine. There are still more options to be filled, I also need some help for it.

```
public class Student {
    private String IDNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String degree;
    private int yearLevel;

    public Student() {
        this.IDNumber = IDNum;
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.middleName = mName;
        this.lastName = lName;
        this.degree = deg;
        this.yearLevel = level;
    }

    public void setIdNumber(String IDNumber) {
        this.IDNumber = IDNumber;
    }

    public String getIdNumber() {
        return IDNumber;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName()
    {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setDegree(String degree) {
        this.degree = degree;
    }

    public String getDegree() {
        return degree;
    }

    public void setYearLevel(int yearLevel) {
        this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
    }

    public int getYearLevel() {
        return yearLevel;
    }

    /* @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ("ID Number: "+this.getIdNumber()+
                    "\nName: "+ this.getFirstName()+
                    " "+ this.getMiddleName()+
                    " "+ this.getLastName()+
                    "\nDegree and YearLevel: "+ this.getDegree() +
                    " - " + this.getYearLevel());
    } */

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu();
    }

    public static void menu() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice = 0;
        System.out.print("****STUDENT RECORD SYSTEM****\n\n");
        System.out.println("\t MENU ");
        System.out.println("[1]ADD STUDENT");
        System.out.println("[2]DISPLAY ALL");
        System.out.println("[3]DISPLAY SPECIFIC");
        System.out.println("[4]UPDATE");
        System.out.println("[5]AVERAGE");
        System.out.println("[6]EXIT");
        System.out.println("?");

        choice = in.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            options();
        }

        else if (choice == 2) {
            displayAll(student, studentList);
        }

        else if (choice == 3) {
            displaySpecific(student, studentList);
        }

    }

    public static void options() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        char ans;
        String temp;

        int total;

        do {

            System.out.println("TOTAL: ");
            total = in.nextInt();

            Student[] student = new Student[total];

            for (int index = 0; index < student.length; index++) {
                student[index] = new Student();

                System.out.print("*********STUDENT INFORMATION*********\n\n");
                System.out.println("PRESS ENTER");
                in.nextLine();
                System.out.print("ID NUMBER: ");
                student[index].setIdNumber(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("FIRST NAME: ");
                student[index].setFirstName(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("MIDDLE NAME: ");
                student[index].setMiddleName(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("LAST NAME: ");
                student[index].setLastName(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("DEGREE: ");
                student[index].setDegree(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("YEAR LEVEL: ");
                student[index].setYearLevel(in.nextInt());

                studentList.add(student[index]);

            }

            System.out
                    .print("Would you like to enter in a new student (y/n)? ");
            String answer = in.next();
            ans = answer.charAt(0);

        } while (ans == 'y');

        // SEARCH and DISPLAY SPECIFIC
        String id = new String();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter ID NUMBER: ");
        id = in.nextLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < studentList.size(); j++) {
            if (id.equals(studentList.get(j).getIdNumber())) {
                System.out.printf("STUDENT SEARCHED");
                System.out.print("\nID NUMBER:             "
                        + studentList.get(j).getIdNumber());
                System.out.print("\nFULL NAME: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getFirstName() + " "
                        + studentList.get(j).getMiddleName() + " "
                        + studentList.get(j).getLastName());
                System.out.print("\nDEGREE and YEAR: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getDegree() + "-"
                        + studentList.get(j).getYearLevel() + "\n\n");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        // DISPLAY ALL
        for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("STUDENT[%d]", i + 1);
            System.out
                    .print("\nID NUMBER: " + studentList.get(i).getIdNumber());
            System.out.print("\nFULL NAME: "
                    + studentList.get(i).getFirstName() + "   "
                    + studentList.get(i).getMiddleName() + " "
                    + studentList.get(i).getLastName());
            System.out.print("\nDEGREE and YEAR: "
                    + studentList.get(i).getDegree() + "-"
                    + studentList.get(i).getYearLevel());
            System.out.println();
        }

        menu();

    }

    public static void displayAll(Student student,
            ArrayList<Student> studentList) {
        System.out.printf("STUDENT RECORD");

        for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("STUDENT[%d]", i + 1);
            System.out
                    .print("\nID NUMBER: " + studentList.get(i).getIdNumber());
            System.out.print("\nFULL NAME: "
                    + studentList.get(i).getFirstName() + " "
                    + studentList.get(i).getMiddleName() + " "
                    + studentList.get(i).getLastName());
            System.out.print("\nDEGREE and YEAR: "
                    + studentList.get(i).getDegree() + "-"
                    + studentList.get(i).getYearLevel());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void displaySpecific(Student student,
            ArrayList<Student> studentList) {
        String id = new String();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter ID NUMBER: ");
        id = in.nextLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < studentList.size(); j++) {
            if (id.equals(studentList.get(j).getIdNumber())) {
                System.out.printf("STUDENT SEARCHED");
                System.out.print("\nID NUMBER: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getIdNumber());
                System.out.print("\nFULL NAME: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getFirstName() + " "
                        + studentList.get(j).getMiddleName() + " "
                        + studentList.get(j).getLastName());
                System.out.print("\nDEGREE and YEAR: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getDegree() + "-"
                        + studentList.get(j).getYearLevel() + "\n\n");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move

```
ArrayList <Student> studentList = new ArrayList <Student>();
```

from `options` method to class field.

EDIT:

As you can see, now studentList is not a local variable of

```
public static void options()
```

but of the class.

Anyway i edited the args of some methods because you don't need to pass students as argument since now it's a field of the class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    static ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu();
    }

    public static void menu() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice = 0;
        System.out.print("****STUDENT RECORD SYSTEM****\n\n");
        System.out.println("\t MENU ");
        System.out.println("[1]ADD STUDENT");
        System.out.println("[2]DISPLAY ALL");
        System.out.println("[3]DISPLAY SPECIFIC");
        System.out.println("[4]UPDATE");
        System.out.println("[5]AVERAGE");
        System.out.println("[6]EXIT");
        System.out.println("?");

        choice = in.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            options();
        }

        else if (choice == 2) {
            displayAll();
        }

        else if (choice == 3) {
            displaySpecific(student);// here  you should ask to the user what studend he want to show - here it continues to give you error
        }

    }

    public static void options() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char ans;
        String temp;

        int total;

        do {

            System.out.println("TOTAL: ");
            total = in.nextInt();

            Student[] student = new Student[total];

            for (int index = 0; index < student.length; index++) {
                student[index] = new Student();

                System.out.print("*********STUDENT INFORMATION*********\n\n");
                System.out.println("PRESS ENTER");
                in.nextLine();
                System.out.print("ID NUMBER: ");
                student[index].setIdNumber(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("FIRST NAME: ");
                student[index].setFirstName(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("MIDDLE NAME: ");
                student[index].setMiddleName(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("LAST NAME: ");
                student[index].setLastName(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("DEGREE: ");
                student[index].setDegree(in.nextLine());

                System.out.print("YEAR LEVEL: ");
                student[index].setYearLevel(in.nextInt());

                studentList.add(student[index]);

            }

            System.out
                    .print("Would you like to enter in a new student (y/n)? ");
            String answer = in.next();
            ans = answer.charAt(0);

        } while (ans == 'y');

        // SEARCH and DISPLAY SPECIFIC
        String id = new String();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter ID NUMBER: ");
        id = in.nextLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < studentList.size(); j++) {
            if (id.equals(studentList.get(j).getIdNumber())) {
                System.out.printf("STUDENT SEARCHED");
                System.out.print("\nID NUMBER:             "
                        + studentList.get(j).getIdNumber());
                System.out.print("\nFULL NAME: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getFirstName() + " "
                        + studentList.get(j).getMiddleName() + " "
                        + studentList.get(j).getLastName());
                System.out.print("\nDEGREE and YEAR: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getDegree() + "-"
                        + studentList.get(j).getYearLevel() + "\n\n");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        // DISPLAY ALL
        for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("STUDENT[%d]", i + 1);
            System.out
                    .print("\nID NUMBER: " + studentList.get(i).getIdNumber());
            System.out.print("\nFULL NAME: "
                    + studentList.get(i).getFirstName() + "   "
                    + studentList.get(i).getMiddleName() + " "
                    + studentList.get(i).getLastName());
            System.out.print("\nDEGREE and YEAR: "
                    + studentList.get(i).getDegree() + "-"
                    + studentList.get(i).getYearLevel());
            System.out.println();
        }

        menu();

    }

    public static void displayAll() {

        for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("STUDENT[%d]", i + 1);
            System.out
                    .print("\nID NUMBER: " + studentList.get(i).getIdNumber());
            System.out.print("\nFULL NAME: "
                    + studentList.get(i).getFirstName() + " "
                    + studentList.get(i).getMiddleName() + " "
                    + studentList.get(i).getLastName());
            System.out.print("\nDEGREE and YEAR: "
                    + studentList.get(i).getDegree() + "-"
                    + studentList.get(i).getYearLevel());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void displaySpecific(Student student) {
        String id = new String();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter ID NUMBER: ");
        id = in.nextLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < studentList.size(); j++) {
            if (id.equals(studentList.get(j).getIdNumber())) {
                System.out.printf("STUDENT SEARCHED");
                System.out.print("\nID NUMBER: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getIdNumber());
                System.out.print("\nFULL NAME: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getFirstName() + " "
                        + studentList.get(j).getMiddleName() + " "
                        + studentList.get(j).getLastName());
                System.out.print("\nDEGREE and YEAR: "
                        + studentList.get(j).getDegree() + "-"
                        + studentList.get(j).getYearLevel() + "\n\n");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how should i do it? what are the changes?

Comment: @kintzee619 Edited. But really, read the code and try to understand the change.

Comment: I already read and studied the changes. Thanks a lot! :) You're my hero!

Comment: hmmn..in the menu() method, displayAll(students) and   displaySpecific(student)when compiling error occurred : student, cannot find symbol..what should i do?

Comment: @kintzee619 Reading your code, Student param in not used at all. Remove it. See edited code, in displaySpecific you should ask to the user who want to see and declare student variable with the student info.

Comment: Just did what said and it worked.Thanks a lot! Sorry for not being good at java, I'm just a beginner and still learning. i hope you can be my teacher. :)

Comment: Accept this answer if everything is ok :)